# kernel and image submodules proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism

Let $f: V\to W$ be a homomorphism of $G$ modules.

Show $\ker f $ is a $G$ submodule of $V$, and  $\mbox{im}f$ is $G$ submodule of $W$ .

Proof: Since $v$ is linear, then we only need to check for closure under the action of $G$. 
Let $a \in\ker f$  and $g\in G$. Then $f(ga) = gf(a) = g(0) = 0.$ So $ga \in \ker f$.

So the $\ker f$ is a $G$ submodule of $V$.

In addition, similarly suppose $a \in V$ and for $g\in G$  we have $gf(a) = f(ga) \in \mbox{im}f$.

So $\mbox{im}f$ is a submodule of $W$

Can someone please verify this and provide feedback? Thank you

Comment: It's correct proof.

Comment: Since **v** is linear ...?